# How to highlight the linkbutton when it's clicked.

Tags: c#, asp.net

Siva here.
       I have used Default aspx page with bunch of link buttons in sidebar. Using asp panel i loaded the user control in panel. Here every thing is perfect. I can't highlight the active link button without post back.

Comment: maybe with some css you could like set color for `a:visited`

Comment: When i click the other link button the highlighted should be applied for new active link button. Other should be normal

Answer (score 0):

ASP has a control called the Update panel (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454(v=vs.100).aspx) 
wich basicly allows you to call events while not using the postback trigger.

i hope this helps.